# Error in SQL Inner Join syntax

Tags: php, sql, syntax, inner-join

I'm using php to innerjoin two tables together, one of which has a space in the field name.

I've tried adding back ticks, regular ticks, but I still get errors and the code will not work.

I can't figure out what my error is, please help.

```
SELECT products.wholesalecost, vendor units.amount
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `vendor units` ON products.productid=vendor units.productid
WHERE vendor units.vorderid=".$row["vorderid"]."
```

Comment: You can't ask about syntax details and keep the involved database system a secret. MySQL I assume from the non-standard backticks?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backticks for every occurence of your table name with space,

```
SELECT products.wholesalecost, `vendor units`.amount
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `vendor units` ON products.productid=`vendor units`.productid
WHERE `vendor units`.vorderid=".$row["vorderid"]."
```

or use an alias for it

```
SELECT products.wholesalecost, vu.amount
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `vendor units` vu ON products.productid=vu.productid
WHERE vu.vorderid=".$row["vorderid"]."
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT `products`.`wholesalecost`, `vendor units`.`amount` ...
ON `products`.`productid` = `vendor units`.`productid`
```

Comment: Didn't work. This is the error i'm getting :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.amount FROM `products` INNER JOIN `vendor units` ON `products`.`productid`=`ven' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a space here: "vendor units".

Comment: thats because my table name has a space in it